# Snow Leopard & LSUIElement -> application not activating properly, window not "active" despite being "key"

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, appkit

I'm running into a few problem with a background application that uses LSUIElement=1 to hide its dock item, menu bar and prevent it from appearing in the Command-Tab application switcher.

It seems to be a Snow Leopard only problem.

The application places an NSStatusItem in the menu bar and pops up a menu when clicked on. Selecting "Preferences..." should bring up an NSWindow with the preferences.

The first thing that doesn't seem to work is that the Window does not get ordered in at the front, but appears behind all other application windows.

I tried to fix this by calling

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES]
```

but that didn't work.

After a while I figured out that the menu is blocking the message to the run loop from being sent, so I wrote another method on the MainController and sent the message with a delay:

[self performSelector:@selector(setFront:) 
              withObject: [preferencesController window] afterDelay:1.0];

```
-(void)setFront: (id) theWindow {

 [[NSApplication sharedApplication]activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
 [theWindow orderFrontRegardless];
 [theWindow makeKeyWindow]; 
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
}
```

Note the send-every-possible-message-to-make-it-do-what-it-should-be-doing-approach.

This works, kind-of, the window is brought to the front on top of all other windows from all apps, BUT most of the time it isn't active, meaning it's title bar is greyed out. Clicking on the title bar won't make the window active either. Clicking INSIDE of the window will make it active!?

This all didn't seem to be a problem in Leopard; just calling activateIgnoringOtherApps and making the window key seemed to work just fine.

In Snow Leopard there is a new API designed to replace LSUIElement that is supposed to emulate its behaviour:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/cocoa/appkit.html

I've played around with that, but it's SL-only and I haven't been able to get LSUIElement being set.

Comment: What you're trying to do can be perceived as stealing the focus, which was made pretty hard. And it's a good thing. What does your menu do? `[preferencesController showWindow:]`?

Comment: It's hardly stealing the focus when the user selects "Preferences..." and you order the preferences window to the front and make it key, but yes the nice people at apple might try to prevent you from doing that.

Answer (score 8):

That's strange - I'm writing a LSUIElement application under Snow Leopard, and I didn't have such problems as you've described... I did have the problem that the newly created window didn't appear at the front, but I fixed it by calling activateIgnoringOtherApps. This was all I had to do to make it work as it should:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES];
[preferencesWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: self];
```

I didn't even touch anything that had 'policy' in the name.

Comment: I think what I experienced was an interaction between the activation policy and something else. The extra code for selecting the activation policy was removed from my program a few weeks ago with no ill effects? It's one of those things that just won't work and then just suddenly starts working just fine again (it could be one of the OS X point updates of course). Perhaps the window I was working with could not become key or main!?

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same situation. But my problem was a little weirder. If I ran it from XCode, it worked perfectly. If I ran the application from Finder, the window wouldn't appear. Adding this line helped so I'm really happy.

Comment: It has been giving me a lot of headaches. Thanks for this elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

After posting the question in desperation, I did continue looking and did eventually find the solution. Since this stumped me for a few days and there seems to be no other answer out there that google can find, I'll explain the solution for "future generations".

Snow Leopard adds a new NSApplication presentationOptions API:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/cocoa/appkit.html

This is supposed to simulate the way that LSUIElement works, but provide more developer control. Unfortunately, the simulation isn't perfect so there is a change of behaviour between 10.5 and 10.6.

In particular, if your application has the LSUIElement = 1 line in its info.plist, Snow Leopard will initialize "the application’s presentationOptions .. to an equivalent combination of NSApplicationPresentationOptions flags instead".

Only it doesn't really. It sets the new NSApplication setActivationPolicy to NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory:

"The application does not appear in the Dock and does not have a menu bar, but it may be activated programmatically or by clicking on one of its windows. This corresponds to value of the LSUIElement key in the application’s Info.plist being 1."

Despite the mention of being activated programatically, activateIgnoringOtherApps: is simply ignored completely.

The solution is to set the activation policy to "regular":

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular];
```

Of course, you can only do this if you use the 10.6 SDK as Base SDK, something few people want to do at the moment, so below is a 10.5-safe way of doing this:

```
NSApplication* app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

if( [app respondsToSelector: @selector(setActivationPolicy:)] ) {

    NSMethodSignature* method = [[app class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector: @selector(setActivationPolicy:)];
    NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: method];
    [invocation setTarget: app];
    [invocation setSelector: @selector(setActivationPolicy:)];
    NSInteger myNSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory = 0;
    [invocation setArgument: &myNSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory atIndex: 2];
    [invocation invoke];

}
```

I hope somebody will find this useful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this effectively brings the Dock icon back.